# Insert a countdown in each node based on a pre-existing date field

Tags: 7, rules, datetime

I would like to put a countdown for each node using a field expiration date (whose values users have already entered).

I explain you my case:

My user publishes an event that have an expiration date (I already have many values for this field inserted by the users and some of them are of events still in progress).
I would like to insert a countdown in each page of the events, based on the expiration date inserted by the user and the date when the user has published the event on my website.

I tried with this module: [field timer](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_timer) but I don't know how to do the connection between this module and the expiration date.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you explain why you need two fields for the same date, really? If they are to be made identical, and nothing ever changes them, why two?!

Comment: You're right, I didn't explain. I've already saved many nodes with the normal expiration date but I'd want to add a countdown related to that date field...if there's a best way to do that please let me know...many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have two fields in one content type - `countdown_date` and `expiration_date`. Both values user has to insert manually. And after submit action, you want to assign `expiration date` to both fields, yes?

Read about [hook_node_submit()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7). In your `MYMODULE_node_submit($node, $form, &$form_state)` you can check the type of content, then assign `expiration_date` to `countdown_date`. This method works with save and preview's action.

For more detailed answer I need more details about these fields.

Comment: Thanks. My users must create only expiration_date of the subscriptions of their event. The countdown_date is set between the "submit day" (the date when the user publishes the node) and the expiration_date. Maybe there's a best way to make a countdown from a pre-existent date field...sorry, I don't have much experience with drupal..